# Upvote/Downvote arrows (bug)

Tags: bug, status-completed

Very teeny-tiny thing, but still. If you've upvoted/downvoted a question/answer, and you try to erase your vote by clicking on the highlighted arrow after quite some time, it'll pop up a message saying that too much time has elapsed for you to revoke it... and "click on this message to dismiss".

Once you do that though, the message disappears, but the arrow reverts to the non-highlighted state.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Your vote stays there, the number doesn't change, but the arrow turns to the 'non-clicked' state.

Comment: More buglets: I've seen a +1, -3 post with a 0 total.  Repeated refresh didn't fix it.

Comment: @hans probably due to spam / offensive flags which carry an implied downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I can repro with FF 3.5 WinXP for both upvotes and downvotes.  Interestingly, the question vote count changed for less than a second — to what the count would have been had the vote been removed — before reverting to the correct value.

I also clicked on the vote count to retrieve the +/- split.  Those numbers, too, are correct.  However, when they get displayed, the arrow still does not change back to the highlighted version.

Comment: I think the "change for less than a second" is okay... SO does that to appear fast. That second is because of network latency... changing that would make it "appear slow", kinda like the Microsoft Windows Vista file copy dialog. (I think Jeff had a blog post about this...)

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't making any value judgments there, just reporting what I saw.